# How to declare a EventSubscriber in config.yml using bazinga_geocoder.geocoder service?

Tags: google-maps, symfony, reverse-geocoding

I am planning to make a reverse geocoding based on the BazingaGeocoderBundle. A simple way to do that is write this simple code in the controller:

```
    $result = $this->container
        ->get('bazinga_geocoder.geocoder')
        ->using('google_maps')
        ->reverse(48.79084170157100,2.42479377175290);
    return $this->render("MinnAdsBundle:Motors:test.html.twig",
            array('result'=>var_dump($result)));
```

Until here, things are going well.

My objective is to make the code nicer & resuable. So, I used this [article](http://michaelsmithonline.blogspot.ae/2012/03/geocoding-in-symfony2-and-doctrine2.html) to write my own GeocoderEventSubscriber as describer below:

```
<?php

namespace Minn\AdsBundle\Doctrine\Event;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
//use Geocoder\Provider\ProviderInterface;
use Bazinga\Bundle\GeocoderBundle\Geocoder\LoggableGeocoder;

/**
 * Subscribes to Doctrine prePersist and preUpdate to update an 
 * the address components of a MotorsAds entity
 * 
 * @author majallouli
 */
class MotorsAdsGeocoderEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriber {

    protected $geocoder;

    public function __construct(LoggableGeocoder $geocoder){
        $this->geocoder = $geocoder;
    }

    /**
    * Specifies the list of events to listen
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function getSubscribedEvents(){
        return array(
            'prePersist',
            'preUpdate',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Sets a new MotorsAds's address components if not present 
     * 
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs 
     */
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs){
        $motorsAds = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        if($motorsAds instanceof \Minn\AdsBundle\Entity\MotorsAds){
            if( !$motorsAds->getCountry()){
                $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
                $this->geocodeMotorsAds($motorsAds,$em);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets an updating MotorsAds's address components if not present 
     * or any part of address updated
     * 
     * @param PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs 
     */
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs){
        $motorsAds = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        if($motorsAds instanceof \Minn\AdsBundle\Entity\MotorsAds){
             if( !$motorsAds->getCountry() ){
                $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
                $this->geocodeMotorsAds($motorsAds,$em);

                $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
                $meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($motorsAds));
                $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $motorsAds);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Geocode and set the MotorsAds's address components
     * 
     * @param type $motorsAds 
     */
    private function geocodeMotorsAds($motorsAds,$em){
        $result = $this->geocode
                ->using('google_maps')
                ->reverse($motorsAds->getLat(),$motorsAds->getLng());
        $motorsAds->setCountry(
                $em->getRepository("MinnAdsBundle:Country")->findCountryCode($result['countryCode']));
    }

}
```

After that, I declared my EventSubscriber as a service:

```
services:
    # ...
    geocoder_motorsads.listener:
        class:  Minn\AdsBundle\Doctrine\Event\MotorsAdsGeocoderEventSubscriber
        arguments: [@bazinga_geocoder.geocoder] # almost sure that the error is here!!
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }
```

Actually, I get this error:

```
ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined property: Minn\AdsBundle\Doctrine\Event\MotorsAdsGeocoderEventSubscriber::$geocode in /home/amine/NetBeansProjects/tuto/src/Minn/AdsBundle/Doctrine/Event/MotorsAdsGeocoderEventSubscriber.php line 78
```

I am almost sure that error is in the declaration of arguments of the EventSubscriber. Is it `@bazinga_geocoder.geocoder`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you try put quotes around your service name? `arguments: ["@bazinga_geocoder.geocoder"]` or you can use simply `arguments: ["@geocoder"]`

Comment: thanks @DebreczeniAndrás for being helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property is `$this->geocoder` but you're calling `$this->geocode`, you're spelling it wrong.